# Google Dialogflow utility for string to integer conversion

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

Is there a Google dialogflow CX function to convert String to Integer? Can a numeric value of String type compared with integer in dialog flow?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly convert String to Number, but for [comparisons, the right hand side is type casted to the same type as the left hand side before comparing](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/condition#:%7E:text=The%20right%20hand%20side%20is%20type%20casted%20to%20the%20same%20type%20as%20the%20left%20hand%20side%20before%20comparing).

This means `5 < "10"` will be evaluated as `5 < 10` for the comparison.